# Dynamoose/DynamoDB update saving empty array as null

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using the Node.js package [Dynamoose](https://github.com/automategreen/dynamoose) to handle DynamoDB requests in my web application.

Problem is when I try to update the item whenever the JSON object includes an empty array Dynamoose seems to set that to null. Or it could be DynamoDB for all I know.

Below is part of my schema that I'm using for this table.

```
var NoteSchema = new dynamoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    details: Array
});
```

In the code below the variable `body` is set to `{details: []}`. I have confirmed this by running `console.log(body);`.

```
Note.update({
    _id: searchid
}, body, function(err, note) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(note);
    }
});
```

Problem is inside that callback function when running `console.log(note);` `details` doesn't even show up at all. So it's null or undefined. In the Amazon Web Services again `details` doesn't exist at all for that entry.

What is so strange is when creating a new Note, setting `details = []`, and saving that, details is an empty array and works perfectly. So to me it seems like a specific problem with updating the record and setting that property to an empty array, since creating a record and setting that property to an empty array works perfectly.

How can I update the record and set details to an empty array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out. Submitted [this issue](https://github.com/automategreen/dynamoose/issues/50) to the GitHub repo. Basically the following line (**lib/Model.js** *about* line 396) of code checks to see if the value is an array with length = 0. If so it will delete that JSON key before sending it to AWS.

```
if(val === null || val === undefined || val === '' || (Array.isArray(val) && val.length === 0)) {
```

I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/automategreen/dynamoose/pull/51) using my [fork](https://github.com/fishcharlie/dynamoose). In that pull request I made the change to allow an *optional* JSON object parameter of options to be passed into the update function. This is the 3rd parameter of the update function and right before the callback function. If there is a key called `emptyarrayallowed` and that value is set to `true` then you that line above will get changed into the following.

```
if(val === null || val === undefined || val === '') {
```

For example in my example above changing the update function to the following will work (as long as you are using my fork or the pull request has been approved).

```
Note.update({_id: searchid}, body, {"emptyarrayallowed": true}, function(err, note) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(note);
    }
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions regarding this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Small update on [Charlie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38758870/1501497). The functionality was merged as mentioned by Charlie. However, looks like the property name was renamed to allowEmptyArray from emptyarrayallowed.